# jqgrid validation when editing a record

Tags: jqgrid

I have now a problem with validation of a record that is being edited.

The edit form (and the add form) has a field called "email". That field should be unique in database, so I use ajax to validate it, by mean of this function:

```
function check_email(value, colname) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckEmail")',
        data: { email: value },
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        datatype: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data) result = [true, ""];
            else result = [false, colname + ": ya existe en el sistema"];
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

This works, but the problem is when I am editing the record. Of course e-mail exists in this case, so it is not allowing me to save the record.

The algorithm might be: it should validate only if id is > 0 and the entered e-mail is different from the existing value. In other words, validation must occur if the user is changing e-mail.

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to know if the editform is for adding or for editing, and even more, I was trying to find the value of the primary key of the record being edited, without any success.

Any help will be appreciated,

EDIT:

This is the code of the grid:

```
    $("#personal").jqGrid({
        url: "@Url.Action("List")",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["Departamento",
                   "Nombres",
                   "Apellido Paterno",
                   "Apellido Materno",
                   "RUT",
                   "Contraseña",
                   "Fecha Nacimiento",
                   "Fotografía",
                   "Estado Civil",
                   "Género",
                   "Dirección",
                   "Cargo",
                   "E-mail",
                   "Fecha Ingreso",
                   "Creación",
                   "Modificación"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "dep_id", index: "dep_nombre", editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: { width: 100, value: "@ViewData["Departamentos"]" }, width: 250, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>' }, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], value: "@ViewData["Departamentos"]" } },
            { name: "per_nombres", index: "per_nombres", editable: true, width: 250, editoptions: { maxlength: 80, size: 32 }, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>' } },
            { name: "per_apellido_paterno", index: "per_apellido_paterno", editable: true, width: 250, editoptions: { maxlength: 80, size: 32 }, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>' } },
            { name: "per_apellido_materno", index: "per_apellido_materno", editable: true, width: 250, editoptions: { maxlength: 80, size: 32 } },
            { name: "per_dni", index: "per_dni", editable: true, width: 100, editoptions: { maxlength: 20, size: 17, dataInit: function (el) { $.mask.definitions['~'] = '[0-9kK]'; $(el).mask("?99.999.999-~"); } }, editrules: { required: true, custom: true, custom_func: is_rut }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: '<span class="required">*</span>' }, searchoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { $.mask.definitions['~'] = '[0-9kK]'; $(el).mask("?99.999.999-~"); } } },
            { name: "per_contrasena", editable: true, edittype: "password", hidden: true, width: 100, editoptions: { maxlength: 50, size: 17 }, editrules: { required: false, edithidden: true } },
            { name: "per_fecha_nacimiento", index: "per_fecha_nacimiento", editable: true, width: 100, editrules: { date: true, required: false }, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'SortableDateTime', newformat: 'd-m-Y' }, editoptions: { size: 17, dataInit: function (el) { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }); $(el).mask("?99-99-9999"); } }, searchoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }); $(el).mask("?99-99-9999"); } } },
            { name: "per_fotografia", index: "per_fotografia", editable: true, width: 250, edittype: "file", editoptions: { maxlength: 255, size: 32 } },
            { name: "per_estado_civil", index: "per_estado_civil", editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: ":;S:Soltero;C:Casado;V:Viudo;D:Divorciado" }, width: 100, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], value: ":;S:Soltero;C:Casado;V:Viudo;D:Divorciado" } },
            { name: "per_sexo", index: "per_sexo", editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: ":;M:Masculino;F:Femenino" }, width: 100, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], value: ":;M:Masculino;F:Femenino" } },
            { name: "per_direccion", index: "per_direccion", editable: true, width: 250, editoptions: { maxlength: 512, size: 32 } },
            { name: "per_cargo", index: "per_cargo", editable: true, width: 100, editoptions: { maxlength: 50, size: 32 } },
            { name: "per_email", index: "per_email", editable: true, width: 100, editoptions: { maxlength: 80, size: 32 }, editrules: { email: true, required: false, custom: true, custom_func: check_email } },
            { name: "per_fecha_ingreso", index: "per_fecha_ingreso", editable: true, width: 100, editrules: { date: true, required: false }, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'SortableDateTime', newformat: 'd-m-Y' }, editoptions: { size: 17, dataInit: function (el) { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }); $(el).mask("?99-99-9999"); } }, searchoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }); $(el).mask("?99-99-9999"); } } },
            { name: "per_creado_el", index: "per_creado_el", editable:false, search:false, width: 100, align: "center", formatter: "date" },
            { name: "per_modificado_el", index: "per_modificado_el", editable:false, search:false, width: 100, align: "center", formatter: "date" },
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "per_id"
        },
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "per_apellido_paterno",
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        multiselect: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        caption: "Funcionarios",
        editurl: "@Url.Action("AjaxEdit")",
        height: '100%',
        width: 935,
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 40            
    });

    $("#personal").jqGrid('hideCol', ["per_fotografia", "per_direccion"]);
    $("#personal").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false }, { width: 500 }, { width: 500 }, {}, { multipleSearch: false, multipleGroup: false });
    $("#personal").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOperators: false });

    $.jgrid.edit.addCaption = "Agregar Funcionario";
    $.jgrid.edit.editCaption = "Modificar Funcionario";
    $.jgrid.edit.saveData = "¡El funcionario fue modificado! ¿Almacena los cambios?";

    $.jgrid.formatter.date.newformat = 'd-m-Y H:i';
```

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: it would be a lot easier if you also posted the code for your grid

Comment: Have the primary key as one of the hidden columns of the grid. Pass the value of this column when making ajax call to the server. In case of addForm the value will be NULL and for editForm, there will be a non null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should send the record ID for verification.

```
function check_email(value, colname) {

    var rowid = jQuery('#personal').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckEmail")',
        data: { email: value, rowid: rowid },
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        datatype: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data) result = [true, ""];
            else result = [false, colname + ": ya existe en el sistema"];
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

and so the server has any record can be checked with the ID does not match with the rowid.

Comment: Asyc :False is depricated,